# Opening new axml page on button click

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I would like to open a new page while pressing a button but I have no clue how this works (because I'm new to Xamarin (Android) programming).

I can barely find anything on the internet / other stackoverflow forums.

When I press @id button1, it should navigate towards the page settings.axml  (Resource.Layout.settings.axml)

I've tried many different things and none of them actually worked for me.

Thanks in advance.
(I appreciate any kind of tips !)

PS: Using Xamarin.Android

Comment: do you use xamarin.forms  or Xamarin.android

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen-tutorial/hello,android_multiscreen_deepdive-tutorial/#Android_Navigation

Comment: @SupunLiyanaarachchi , I'm using Xaramin.Android but forgot to add it into the question

Comment: ok then try my answer xamarin.android method. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/page-navigation-in-xamarin-android-app-using-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use Xamarin.Android

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);  
button.Click += delegate {  StartActivity(typeof(settings)) };
```

if you use xamarin.Forms

```
private void button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     App.Current.MainPage = new settings();
}
```

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/page-navigation-in-xamarin-android-app-using-visual-studio-2015/
- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/